# Can't login with domain user after ADSys installation - fetching policy fails, getting GPT.ini invalid argument error

Tags: 22.04, dconf, active-directory, sssd, ubuntu-pro

I've implemented Adsys in a virtual environment containing a an ubuntu 22.04 pro and a regular ubuntu 20.04 and an AD server running windows server 2022.
Before installing the ADSys the computers had no issue with login into the domain using sssd.
Once I install it I can't login and when trying to use adsysctl update I keep getting these errors (running from local user because I can't login with domain user):

```
user@UBU-TEST:~$ sudo adsysctl update -m -vv
INFO No configuration file: Config File "adsys" Not Found in "[/home/user /root /etc /usr/sbin]".
We will only use the defaults, env variables or flags.
DEBUG Connecting as [[2696:944129]]
DEBUG New request /service/UpdatePolicy
DEBUG Requesting with parameters: IsComputer: true, All: false, Target: UBU-TEST, Krb5Cc:
DEBUG NormalizeTargetName for "UBU-TEST", type "computer"
DEBUG Check if grpc request peer is authorized
DEBUG Authorized as being administrator
DEBUG GetPolicies for "UBU-TEST", type "computer"
DEBUG Getting gpo list with arguments: "--objectclass computer ldap://dc-test.domain.local UBU-TEST"
DEBUG GPO "Linux Policy" for "UBU-TEST" available at "smb://DOMAIN.LOCAL/SysVol/DOMAIN.LOCAL/Policies/{7D9D6339-27D9-462E-851A-47EE38ABD455}"
DEBUG Analyzing "assets"
DEBUG Analyzing "Linux Policy"
INFO No assets directory with GPT.INI file found on AD, skipping assets download
ERROR Error from server: error while updating policy: can't get policies for "UBU-TEST": can't download all gpos and assets: one or more error while fetching GPOs and assets: can't download "Linux Policy": can't check if Linux Policy needs refreshing: no GPT.INI file: cannot open smb://DOMAIN.LOCAL/SysVol/DOMAIN.LOCAL/Policies/{7D9D6339-27D9-462E-851A-47EE38ABD455}/GPT.INI: invalid argument
```

I've followed the adsys whitepaper step by step including the AD integration part, and downloaded the needed admx and adml files, and also installed the adwatchd daemon.
I can not find any information online explaining what causes this error, why the computer is unable to get the policy (also cancelled inheritance so it would only get the ubuntu policy) and how to fix.

Does anyone have any idea on how to solve it?